# How to skip end-tags (HTML) in VS code editor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, visual-studio-code

I have installed VS code editor with default settings. When I type a html code, for example the starting tag, `<title>` the ending tag is automatically generated i.e. `</title>`. But after typing the title inside those tags. I have to press 'right arrow' button repeatedly(here, 8 times) to come out of this HTML element(`</title>` tag).

Is there any shortcut such that I don't have to press 'right arrow' button repeatedly and instead any single key, which will skip the closing tag in one stroke of any button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open keyboard shortcut settings, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on windows or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on mac and type `keyboard shortcuts`. Select the first option.

[image]

search for `cursorLineEnd`. Set any keyboard key combination, if not already set.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This just moves to the end of the line. It doesn't skip past the closing tag, unless it is at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Mac, it's `cmd + right arrow`. If you're on Linux/Windows, it's `ctrl + right arrow`. This doesn't skip the closing tag but skips to the end of the line, which close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can type the ending tag and it'll also progress through it as if the autocompleted version wasn't there.

You can also use ctrl+right arrow to skip to the end of the line.

And if you use the Emmet extension, you can just press tab.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Ctrl+right arrow 
and scan that link 
https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/cxxyj2/how_to_skip_to_end_of_closing_tag_end_of_line_or/